# Auto-layout interfering with UItextfield text size and adjust to fit property

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, ios8, autolayout

I recently implemented auto-layout on my app in order to scale it for all iPhone sizes. I noticed a tiny problem after I implemented it however. If I click the adjust to fit button on my UITextfields, when I run my app, the UITextfields automatically adjust to the minimum font size that I set instead of slowly scaling down as I add text to them like I want them to do. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Here is an example of some of the constraints i'm using: [image]

Comment: Does the scaling happen properly without the adjust to fit option? Can you post a screenshot of your constraints?

Comment: Yes, i've added it above....The scaling happens properly for all iPhone models, but when I include the adjust to fit option, the placeholder text as well as the input text is much smaller. At the size of my minimum adjustable font size.

Comment: http://imgur.com/Znv13KD  Here is my configuration. As you can see, I have set the auto layout constraints as you have and adjust to fit is set by default.The font starts out at 21 which is what I have set and shrinks to 17 when the text fills the entire textbox. Please check your configuration with the above and upload your project on onedrive/dropbox if this does not solve the problem

Comment: Thanks, I'll test it some more and see if I can get it to work...Let me get back to you. Appreciate the help thus far.

Comment: No problem. Let me know about any further progress

Comment: Hey @RajeevBhatia, I just wanted to give you an update. I could never get my textFields to adjust font correctly. It kept giving me the smallest minimum font when I tried setting all the attributes in my interface builder. When I set the default text size programmatically however, and then checked the adjust font size box, the text edited itself appropriately. Probably just a bug in the interface builder. Thanks for the assistance!